# How can i test my resolvers properly with jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, ts-jest, typegraphql

I'm trying to test my resolvers but i'd like to test each field of the response, here's the code to call the response:

```
interface Options {
  source: string;
  variableValues?: Maybe<{ [key: string]: unknown | null }>;
}

let schema: GraphQLSchema;

const gCall = async ({
  source,
  variableValues,
}: Options): Promise<ExecutionResult> => {
  if (!schema) {
    schema = await createSchema();
  }
  return graphql({
    schema,
    source,
    variableValues,
  });
};

export default gCall;
```

And that's the code to test the resolver:

```
let connection: Connection;
const challengeMutation = `
mutation CreateChallenge($data: CreateChallengeInput!) {
  createChallenge(data: $data) {
    id
    name
    category
    startDate
    endDate
    goal
    description
  }
}
`;

describe('Create Challenge', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await databaseTestConnection();
    await connection.createQueryBuilder().delete().from(Challenge).execute();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.createQueryBuilder().delete().from(Challenge).execute();
    await connection.close();
  });

  it('should create challenge', async () => {
    const challenge = {
      name: 'some awesome name',
      category: 'distância',
      startDate: new Date(2020, 7, 4).toISOString(),
      endDate: new Date(2020, 7, 5).toISOString(),
      goal: 5000,
      description: 'some excelent challenge description',
    };

    const response = await gCall({
      source: challengeMutation,
      variableValues: {
        data: challenge,
      },
    });

    expect(response).toMatchObject({
      data: {
        createChallenge: {
          name: challenge.name,
          category: challenge.category,
          startDate: challenge.startDate,
          endDate: challenge.endDate,
          goal: challenge.goal,
          description: challenge.description,
        },
      },
    });
  });
});
```

What I'd like to do is test the fields separately, like this:

```
expect(response.data.createChallenge.name).toEqual(challenge.name);
```

But I'm getting the following error when I try to execute the above code:

```
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
```

What can I do to solve this error and to make this test better?

Answer (score 0):

> Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.

TypeScript warns you that the response data might not exist as the graphql "server" might return error instead. So you should use `!` operator to assert it's not null.

You should also do that after checking it's not undefined with `expect()`.